# Regex to Match Characters in Words in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Hi i am Trying to Match Characters in Words Same as Email Search while Sending Emails. Where popover is shown. By Typing text, Text is Highlighted in Popover.

```
Anna Haro
anna-haro@mac.com
Hank M. Zakroff
hank-zakroff@mac.com
```

what is Tried is,

```
\bHa[\w-]*
```

Expecting Match as,

Anna **Ha**ro

anna-haro@mac.com

**Ha**nk M. Zakroff

**ha**nk-zakroff@mac.com

Comment: Please add a little more code. How have you used this regex?

Comment: What is your issue? Could you put it simply what results give your current regex, and what do you want, if they are differences?

Comment: you can filter array with `NSPredicate` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the way that you can highlight search string from whole  string.

`Step 1` : Add following method. that is created `NSRegularExpression` object for you.

```
- (NSRegularExpression *)regularExpressionWithString:(NSString *)string options:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    // Create a regular expression
    BOOL isCaseSensitive = [[options objectForKey:kRWSearchCaseSensitiveKey] boolValue];
    BOOL isWholeWords = [[options objectForKey:kRWSearchWholeWordsKey] boolValue];

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpressionOptions regexOptions = isCaseSensitive ? 0 : NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive;

    NSString *placeholder = isWholeWords ? @"\\b%@\\b" : @"%@";
    NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:placeholder, string];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:regexOptions error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create regex with given string and options");
    }

    return regex;
}
```

Step 2 : Here are the code that highlight the find string from whole string.

```
// 4: Call the convenient method to create a regex for us with the options we have
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [self regularExpressionWithString:searchString options:options];

    // 5: Find matches
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:visibleText options:NSMatchingProgress range:visibleTextRange];

    // 6: Iterate through the matches and highlight them
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
    {
        NSRange matchRange = match.range;
        [visibleAttributedText addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:matchRange];
    }
```

[Refer for more help](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet)

**Edit :**

**Replace**

```
 NSString *placeholder = @"\\b%@";
```

**With**

```
NSString *placeholder = isWholeWords ? @"\\b%@\\b" : @"%@";
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: thanks, but its not working in my case. anna-haro@mac.com **ha** is also highlighting. it should start highlighting from beginning of word only.

Comment: @cdon, that means you don't  want to search string inside Whole text. just highlight only text that has starting index(prefix text)..

Comment: @cdon, can you please replace `@"\\b%@\\b"` with `@"\\b %@\\b"`? and check out weather is it working fine or not ?

Comment: @Nope, No its not working for me.     NSString *placeholder = isWholeWords ? @"\\b %@\\b" : @"%@";

Comment: @cdon, i think you miss some syntax. kinldy check my updated answer.

Comment: @cdon, there should be 1 white space at beginning of @" %@"

Comment: i have checkout in sample code that you can download from reference url and doing this changes working fine as per your requirement

Comment: @Nope can u provide me a sample project link.

Comment: @cdon, i have download sample from [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet) url and do the minor change as up i edit my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76987/discussion-between-none-and-cdon).

Comment: Once again i have update solution that is final as per your requirement. replace `NSString *placeholder = @"\\b%@";` with `NSString *placeholder = isWholeWords ? @"\\b%@\\b" : @"%@";`....